# Nginx and DigitalOcean doesn't work with 'www'

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

I'm pretty new to the whole server, Nginx and DigitalOcean topic... 
I deployed my website and when one tries to open the website over the url: 'antonwy.com' or 'http://antonwy.com' everything works, but if you use 'www.antonwy.com' it doesn't work...

**My Nginx config:**

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   root /var/www/antonwy.com;
   server_name www.antonwy.com antonwy.com;
   index index.html index.htm;
   location / {
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's DNS entry issue. add A or CNAME record for www